# Как добавить действие в PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Мне нужно добавить сюда дополниткльные вкладки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать? Даже не знаю как эта штука называется
Помогите пж

Comment: Попробуйте внести изменения в какие-нибудь файлы, не появится после этого?

Comment: @insolor, console появился, а local change нет

Comment: Похоже на вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62577792/4752653 В Settings через поиск найдите non-modal commit interface и снимите галку, тогда появится и Local changes, и коммит в отдельном окне будет выполняться.